# Regular expression to get email ids from data

Tags: jquery, regex, node.js

I am new to regular expressions. I have following data, from this I want to get the unique email id. How it is possible using a regular expression?

```
 commit 01
 emailid: Tests <tests@gmail.com>
 Date:   Wed Jun 18 12:55:55 2014 +0530

 details

 commit 02
 emailid: user <user@gmail.com>
 Date:   Wed Jun 18 12:55:55 2014 +0530

  location
 commit 03
 emailid: Tests <tests@gmail.com>
 Date:   Wed Jun 18 12:55:55 2014 +0530

    france24
 commit 04
 emailid: developer <developer@gmail.com>
 Date:   Wed Jun 18 12:55:55 2014 +0530

    seloger
```

From this using regular expression how can I retrieve `tests@gmail.com,user@gmail.com,developer@gmail.com`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With this regex:

```
emailid: [^<]*<([^>]*)
```

- `emailid:` matches that string literal
- `[^<]*<` matches any characters that are not a `<`, then matches `<`
- `([^>]*)` captures all characters that are not a `>` to Group 1. This is your emailid.

In [the regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/aQ2cU4), look at the Group captures in the right pane. This is what we are looking for.

**Getting Unique emailids**

For each match, we check if the emailid is already in our array of unique email ids. See the output of this [JS demo](http://js.do/code/39764).

```
var uniqueids = [];
var string = 'blah emailid: Tests <tests@gmail.com>  emailid: user <user@gmail.com> emailid: Tests <tests@gmail.com> emailid: developer <developer@gmail.com>'
var regex = /emailid: [^<]*<([^>]*)/g;
var thematch = regex.exec(string);
while (thematch != null) {
    // print the emailid, or do whatever you want with it
    if(uniqueids.indexOf(thematch[1]) <0) {
        uniqueids.push(thematch[1]);
        document.write(thematch[1],"<br />");    
    }
    thematch = regex.exec(string);
}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55901/discussion-between-zx81-and-sush).